# Why doesn't loss function decrease under 1.5?

Tags: python, machine-learning, mnist

I'm trying to do machine learning using mnist dataset in pytorch, but the loss function doesn't decrease under 1.5.

I want the loss function to decrease under 1.

What to do for this problem?

what code should I fix?

This is my code:

```py
BATCH_SIZE = 8

transform =torchvision.transforms.Compose([torchvision.transforms.ToTensor(),torchvision.transforms.Normalize((0.5,), (0.5,))])

trainset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root = "./data/train", train = True, download = True, transform = transform)

trainset, valset = torch.utils.data.random_split(trainset, [50000, 10000])

trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(trainset, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, shuffle = True)

valloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(valset, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, shuffle = True)

testset = torchvision.datasets.MNIST(root = "./data/test", train = False, download = True, transform = transform)

testloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(testset, batch_size = BATCH_SIZE, shuffle = False

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(2, stride=2)

        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1,20,5)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(20,50,5)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(50,500,4)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(500,10,1)

        self.soft = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = self.pool(x)
        x = self.conv3(x)
        x = self.relu(x)
        x = self.conv4(x)

        x = self.soft(x)

        x = x.view(x.size()[0], -1)

        return x


class EarlyStopping:
    """earlystopping class"""

    def __init__(self, patience=5, verbose=False, path='checkpoint_model.pth'):
       
        self.patience = patience   
        self.verbose = verbose     
        self.counter = 0          
        self.best_score = None    
        self.early_stop = False   
        self.val_loss_min = np.Inf 
        self.path = path            

    def __call__(self, valid_loss):

        score = -valid_loss

        if self.best_score is None: 
            self.best_score = score 
            self.checkpoint(valid_loss) 
        elif score - self.best_score < 0.0001:  
            self.counter += 1   
            if self.verbose: 
                print(f'EarlyStopping counter: {self.counter} out of {self.patience}') 
            if self.counter >= self.patience: 
                self.early_stop = True
        else: 
            self.best_score = score
            self.checkpoint(valid_loss) 
            self.counter = 0 

    def checkpoint(self, valid_loss):
  
        if self.verbose: 
            print(f'Validation loss decreased ({self.val_loss_min:.6f} --> {valid_loss:.6f}).')
        self.val_loss_min = valid_loss 

earlystopping = EarlyStopping(patience=5, verbose=True)

net = Net()
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
optimizer = optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.00005, momentum=0.9, weight_decay=0.005)

train_loss=[]  
train_acc=[]    
val_loss=[]    
val_acc=[]       

if __name__ == '__main__':

    BATCH_SIZE = 8

    start = time.time()

    for epoch in range(10000):

        print('epoch', epoch+1)

        sum_loss = 0.0 
        sum_correct = 0 
        sum_total = 0  

        #Training
        net = net.train()
        for (inputs, labels) in trainloader:
            #inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            sum_loss += loss.item()                            #Add loss
            _, predicted = outputs.max(1)                      
            sum_total += labels.size(0)                        
            sum_correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()

        print("train mean loss={}, accuracy={}"
                .format(sum_loss*BATCH_SIZE/len(trainloader.dataset), float(sum_correct/sum_total)))
        train_loss.append(sum_loss*BATCH_SIZE/len(trainloader.dataset))

        train_acc.append(float(sum_correct/sum_total))

        sum_loss = 0.0
        sum_correct = 0
        sum_total = 0

        #Validating
        net = net.eval()
        for (inputs, labels) in valloader:
            #inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            outputs = net(inputs)
            loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
            sum_loss += loss.item()
            _, predicted = outputs.max(1)
            sum_total += labels.size(0)
            sum_correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()

            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
        print("valid  mean loss={}, accuracy={}"
                .format(sum_loss*BATCH_SIZE/len(valloader.dataset), float(sum_correct/sum_total)))
        val_loss.append(sum_loss*BATCH_SIZE/len(valloader.dataset))
        val_acc.append(float(sum_correct/sum_total))

        #Early stop
        earlystopping(val_loss[-1])
        if earlystopping.early_stop:
            print("Early Stopping!")
            break

    finish_time = time.time() - start

    #Test
    net.test()
    test_loss = 0
    correct = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for (inputs, labels) in testloader:
            output = net(inputs)
            test_loss += criterion(output, labels).item()
            pred = output.argmax(dim=1, keepdim=True)
            correct += pred.eq(labels.view_as(pred)).sum().item()

        test_loss /= 10000
        test_acc = correct / 10000
```

And this is the resulting image.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eln4S.png

The loss function converges without going below 1.5, and earlystopping terminates machine learning.

Comment: What would you expect to happen instead?

Comment: That's usually mean you don't have a correct hyperparameter or your model is not deep enough, or indeed the model and data can just achieve that 1.5 loss, but in mnist dataset case which does not need a deep neural network, it might be your optimizer. Btw i did not read all of your code, tell me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

Since I have done a similar task (with a different but comparable network) I know that the Loss when using `cross_entropy` decreases lower than 1.5. In my case accuracy was ~95% and the loss ~0.200. When inspecting your [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eln4S.png) I saw that for the test loss (in the picture you named it Loss evaluate) the value matches with what one should expect for train/val loss after some epochs. So there is most likely an error when computing the loss for the training and validation phases.

You compute the loss for a certain epoch like this:

```
train_loss.append(sum_loss*BATCH_SIZE/len(trainloader.dataset))
```

`len(trainloader.dataset)` does not return number of batches but rather number of samples, thus using BATCH_SIZE for computing the loss is correct and necessary. See [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-is-len-dataloader-equal-to/52472/5).

Since Cross_Entropy by default reports the mean for the batch (see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html)) using

```
sum_loss*BATCH_SIZE/len(trainloader.dataset)
```

is correct if the trainloader actually has a Batch-size equal to the one defined in the provided code. Since you did not share the part where the trainloader was defined I cannot be sure.

What indicates this behaviour is that in the test part you don't use `len(testloader.dataset)` but rather hardcoded 10000 to get the mean for the epoch, I think that the dataloader (for all train, validate and testing) may not have batch size equal to BATCH_SIZE and is most likely 1.